# How can I cascade a JPA persist operation to a child entity when the parent has a generated identity?

Tags: jpa

I have a bi-directional `@OneToOne` relationship between a parent entity and a child entity.

In the parent, I have this (yes, the child is the owning side of the relationship):

```
@OneToOne(mappedBy = "parent", fetch = FetchType.EAGER, optional = true, cascade = { CascadeType.ALL })
private Child child;
```

His primary key is (regrettably) generated by the database:

```
@Column(name = "id", updatable = false)
@GeneratedValue(GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Id
private long id;
```

In the child, I have this:

```
// note: insertable = false, updatable = false
@JoinColumn(name = "parentId", referencedColumnName = "id", insertable = false, updatable = false)
@OneToOne(optional = false, fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = { CascadeType.REFRESH })
private Parent parent;

@Column(name = "parentId", updatable = false)
@Id
private long parentId;
```

Normally I would use a `@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn` annotation instead of these two mappings, but a couple of JPA providers have bugs in this area.

At some point, I do some work on a new parent instance.  As part of that work I do this:

```
this.child = new Child(this);
```

...and inside the `Child(Parent)` constructor I do this:

```
this.parent = parent; // now the bidirectionality is complete
if (parent != null) {
  this.parentId = parent.getId(); // suspect; will be 0L
}
```

So if you're with me so far I have an object graph consisting of a `Parent` and a `Child` who have `@OneToOne` relationships with one another, properly initialized.  Both objects are unmanaged entities.

Then I try to `persist()` the parent:

```
this.em.persist(parent);
```

...and I get a foreign key violation on our Informix database.  On the other hand, our H2 database processes this just fine.

Is that what should be happening?  Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I have some questions that might help you. Please answer them in your original post:

Q1: are you sure you have a foreign key & primary key constraint in the the H2 database (check it)?

Q2: What about the `NULLABLE` flag? (both databases)

Q3: Debug and check what is the ID of the parentId in the child in the moment when you call persist().

Q4: Would it be possible to remove the `CascadeType.ALL` from parent and to manage the operation(s) manually (or only persist)?

Hope answering one of the questions will give you the solution to your problem.